# Using Apache on port 8081, Nginx on port 80 and UWSGI using file socket for a Django App works on port 8000 but not on port 80

Tags: django, apache, nginx, cpanel, uwsgi

As we have cPanel Linux Server (Centos 6.4) we have set it up to use Nginx on Port 80 (using: http://nginxcp.com/ )

I have setup UWSGI following this: 
https://uwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/Django_and_nginx.html

Everything works perfectly as expected if I have listen set to 8000 and use http://example.com:8000 however if I use port 80 , it only shows server docroot file tree.

Any suggestions why or tips for me to fix this issue.

Some info on setup:

result of netstat -tulpn | grep :80

```
tcp        0      0 162.216.x.xx:80             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19656/nginx
tcp        0      0 162.216.x.xx:80             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19656/nginx
tcp        0      0 162.216.x.xx:80             0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      19656/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8081                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      16329/httpd
```

my nginx.conf :

```
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///var/uwsgi/incitollc.sock; # for a file socket
    }

# configuration of the server

    server {
        # the port your site will be served on
        listen      80;
        # the domain name it will serve for
        server_name example.biz www.example.biz 162.216.5.82; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
        root /home/example/public_html/exampleapp;
        access_log /home/example/public_html/logs/access.log;
        error_log /home/example/public_html/logs/error.log;
        charset     utf-8;

        # max upload size
        client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

        # Django media
        location /media  {
            alias /home/example/public_html/exampleapp/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
        }

        location /static {
            alias /home/example/public_html/exampleapp/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        }

        # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
        location / {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /home/example/public_html/uwsgi_params;
            }
        }
```

My uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]

chdir           = /home/example/public_html/exampleapp
module          = exampleapp.wsgi:application
home        = /home/example/public_html/exampleappenv
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket      = /var/uwsgi/exampleapp.sock
chmod-socket    = 666
vacuum          = true
gid         = nobody
uid         = nobody
pidfile     = /var/uwsgi/exampleapp.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by changing:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:///var/uwsgi/incitollc.sock; # for a file socket
    }
```

to:

```
upstream django {
    server unix:/var/uwsgi/incitollc.sock; # for a file socket
    }
```